# Display image on keyboard input and save input to file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The language (php, html, javascript) really doesn't matter here, but I am looking for a solution to take user input from the keyboard and advance through images in a directory. After the image displays, the user would then press a key, saving the input to a file on the server.

Files are all .pngs in the same directory, so script would apriori know which images to display. So basically:

1) Page displays image from array on pageload

2) User presses a key depending on the image shown

3) That input is saved to a text file on the server

4) The next image is loaded and the process repeats until the image array is finished

Here is the .php code that I have so far. I am able to capture the keyboard input, but I cannot seem to get the image displayed or the proper $post code to save keyboard input to a file.

```
<?php
$dir = getcwd()."/";
$fileType = ".png";
$width = "663";
$height = "733";
$folder = basename($dir);
$filelist = glob("$dir*$fileType");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
var key_code = event.keyCode;
document.getElementById('kp').innerHTML = key_press;
document.getElementById('kc').innerHTML = key_code;
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = "DOWN Event Fired For : "+key_press;
if(key_press == "Y"){
    document.body.style.background = "lime";
} else if(key_press == "N") {
    document.body.style.background = "red";
} else if(key_press == "M") {
    document.body.style.background = "yellow";
}
}
document.onkeyup = function(event){
var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = "UP Event Fired For : "+key_press;
document.body.style.background = "white";
}
</script>
<h2>Capture Response from Keyboard</h2>
<h3>onkeydown - onkeyup</h3>
Key Pressed : <span id="kp"></span>
<br />
Key Code : <span id="kc"></span>
<p id="status">Keyboard Event Status</p>
```

Comment: You are doing some stuff in your php, but it's not affecting the page at all. `$filelist` contains an array of your `.png` files. You need your javascript to access that data. To do that you must echo it out somewhere (probably inside your javascript), and probably encode it (`echo json_encode($filelist);`). In order to save your keypresses to the server, you have to actually make a request to that server to do something. Write another php script that expects a character in the request body (As in a POST request). When a key is pressed, send an ajax request to that script with the character.

Comment: Do you have an example? If so, I can choose it as the answer!

Comment: added below with comments to help you understand what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I've included comments explaining what was done along the way.

As I was saying, you need to actually do something with the data you retrieve from your server.

```
<?php
  //This truncates the document when the page is refreshed.
  fopen("saved_chars.txt", "w+");

  //Get the images in the same folder as this script
  $dir = getcwd()."/";
  $fileType = ".png";
  $width = "663";
  $height = "733";
  $folder = basename($dir);
  $filelist = glob("$dir*$fileType", GLOB_NOESCAPE);

  //Because glob() returns absolute filepaths on the server, we need
  //to replace the current directory with an empty string, so we
  //are left with the image filepaths, relative to the webpage's location.
  $n_filelist = array();
  foreach($filelist as $filename){
    $filename = str_replace($dir,"",$filename);
    array_push($n_filelist,$filename);
  }
  $filelist = $n_filelist;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Capture Response from Keyboard</h2>
  <h3>onkeydown - onkeyup</h3>
  <img src="" id="myImage"></img><br/><br/>
  <span>Key Pressed : <span id="kp"></span>
  <br />
  <span>Key Code : <span id="kc"></span>
  <p id="status">Keyboard Event Status</p>
</body>
<script>

  //here we are transforming the php $filelist array into a javascript array
  //by using the function `json_encode`
  //this must be done so as javascript is processed seperatly (on the client) to the php (which is done on the server).
  var files = <?php echo json_encode($filelist); ?>;

  var cIndex = 0;

  function displayNextImage(files){
    //here we check if the cIndex (current index) is less than the number of files. if it is, we can safely display the next image, and increment cIndex.
    if(cIndex < files.length){
      displayImage(files[cIndex++]);
    }
  }

  var isSaving = false;

  function saveKeyToServer(key){
    //here we send a "POST" request to out other script, savechar.php
    //savechar.php will simply write the pressed character into a file
    //we use a boolean value, isSaving, to track if a request is currently
    //in progress. This protects up from users spamming key presses before the new image loads.
    if(isSaving == false){
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           displayNextImage(files);
           //once the request has been resolved and the new image displayed,
           //we can safely process user input again
           isSaving = false;
        }
      }; 
      isSaving = true;
      xhttp.open("POST", "savechar.php", true);
      xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"pressed" : key}));
    }
  }

  function displayImage(imageName){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src=imageName;
  }

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var key_code = event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById('kp').innerHTML = key_press;
    document.getElementById('kc').innerHTML = key_code;
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = "DOWN Event Fired For : " + key_press;
    if(key_press == "Y"){
        document.body.style.background = "lime";
        saveKeyToServer(key_press);
    } else if(key_press == "N") {
        document.body.style.background = "red";
        saveKeyToServer(key_press);
    } else if(key_press == "M") {
        document.body.style.background = "yellow";
        saveKeyToServer(key_press);
    }
  }

  document.onkeyup = function(event){
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = "UP Event Fired For : "+key_press;
    document.body.style.background = "white";
  }

  //we call this here, so that the first image is displayed
  displayNextImage(files)

</script>
</html>
```

`savechar.php` simply must write to a file. It should be in the same directory as the above file (along with the images).

```
<?php
  $pressed_key = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true)["pressed"];
  $fh = fopen("saved_chars.txt","a");
  fwrite($fh, $pressed_key);
  fclose($fh);
?>
```

And boom, assuming file permissions are set up correctly on your server, this should be good to go.

Comment: I assume to add more to the file (e.g., image filename with key pressed) I need to edit the saveKeyToServer function and fwrite($fh, $pressed_key); to add the additional filename variable?

Comment: Yup. Simply pass along whatever you want, as a JSON object ( where I pass `{"pressed" : key}`, so you could pass along something like `{"pressed" : key, "image" : myimagefile}` ). When I use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true)` in `savechar.php` it is simply returning an array, where you can access any value you passed along to it (In my example, it's immediatly getting the "pressed" value).

Comment: Sorry for all the dumb questions...

I tried: xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"filname" : files[cIndex]}));

and:

<?php
  $pressed_key = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true)["pressed"];
  $imname = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true)["filname"];
  $fh = fopen("saved_chars.txt","a");
  fwrite($fh, $imname."-".$pressed_key);
?>

in the savechar.php.  Cannot seem to get it to display the imagename in the file though. It is left blank, so I suspect it's not getting set properly.

Comment: I got it...thanks for your assistance. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, it could be a few things. Are you just sending `xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"filname" : files[cIndex]}));`? If you are sending that without also sending along "pressed", `savechar.php` will throw an exception when you run it, as it will be trying to access the non-existant index "pressed" still. Try `xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"filname" : files[cIndex], "pressed" : key}));`, so both are being sent. Then on your server, try `$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true); $pressed_key = $postdata["pressed"]; $imname = $postdata["filname"];`